# Deploying endpoints app into appengine with appcfg.py

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

The documentation describes how to deploy endpoints application with `gcloud` tool but is it possible to deploy the app with `appcfg.py`?

What I'd like is to use this command:

```
appcfg.py update [YOUR_APP_DIR] -A [YOUR_PROJECT_ID] -V [YOUR_VERSION_ID]
```

And don't have to edit the `app.yaml` file to set a new value for `ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_VERSION` variable every time I need to deploy a new version.

If I understand correctly `YOUR_VERSION_ID` application version is not the same as `ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_VERSION` but where this difference is important?

Comment: Curiosity - why do you want to use appcfg.py?  `gcloud app` is going to be way more up to date.

Comment: Up until I started playing with endpoints, the only thing I needed to deploy my application into AE standard was `appcfg.py update` and that tool is coming with App Engine Python SDK which I'm already using. So there was no need in installing full Google Cloud SDK. I hoped it could stay that way but with an extra step of deploying OpenAPI spec with `gcloud service-management deploy` command, seems I'll have to start using `gcloud` anyway, unless it'd be possible to do the same with `appcfg.py` as well.

Comment: OK, after reading more about [Microservices Architecture on Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine) and [Handling API Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/handling-api-versioning) I understand now that application service versions have nothing to do with endpoints service versions. And it seems you can actually deploy multiple endpoints service versions inside one application version, but the documentation doesn't explain use cases of such architecture.